# cannot convert argument 1 from 'char *' to 'const caffe::NetParameter

Tags: c++, matlab, caffe, mex, matcaffe

i have this issue when building opencl caffe with matlab .

> "D:\Projects\shawkat\caffe-opencl\caffe-opencl\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
>   "D:\Projects\shawkat\caffe-opencl\caffe-opencl\build\Matlab\matlab.vcxproj" (default target) (25) ->
>   (ClCompile target) ->
>   D:\Projects\shawkat\caffe-opencl\caffe-opencl\matlab+caffe\private\caffe_.cpp(285): error C2664: 'caffe::Net:
>   :Net(const caffe::Net &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'char *' to 'const caffe::NetParameter &' [D:\Projects
>   \shawkat\caffe-opencl\caffe-opencl\build\Matlab\matlab.vcxproj

the problem is in function get_net in file `caffe_.cpp`
here is this function from the file

```
// Usage: caffe_('get_net', model_file, phase_name)

static void get_net(MEX_ARGS) {
  mxCHECK(nrhs == 2 && mxIsChar(prhs[0]) && mxIsChar(prhs[1]),
      "Usage: caffe_('get_net', model_file, phase_name)");
  char* model_file = mxArrayToString(prhs[0]);
  char* phase_name = mxArrayToString(prhs[1]);
  mxCHECK_FILE_EXIST(model_file);
  Phase phase;
  if (strcmp(phase_name, "train") == 0) {
      phase = TRAIN;
  } else if (strcmp(phase_name, "test") == 0) {
      phase = TEST;
  } else {
    mxERROR("Unknown phase");
  }
  shared_ptr<Net<float> > net(new caffe::Net<float>(model_file, phase));
  nets_.push_back(net);
  plhs[0] = ptr_to_handle<Net<float> >(net.get());
  mxFree(model_file);
  mxFree(phase_name);
}
```

Comment: it seems like you are passing a string (file name) when in fact your function expects a parsed file object.

Comment: okay thanks for your quick comment 
now model_file and phase_name are strings
and they show error in this line 
  shared_ptr<Net<float> > net(new caffe::Net<float>(model_file, phase));
as i stated earlier 
what should i do in this line or in the initial of these variables ?

Comment: i tried also to build with ninja and i got the same error

Comment: @HeshamMohamed can you please provide an already built matcaffe?

Comment: here it is but there is a good chance that it will not work for you because you have to build it on your platform from the beginning to actually work 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Byz3GHMzuz2xTzktRGhXb25UVHM

Answer (score 1):

solved by adding NULL as a third input to the function as follow 
  shared_ptr > net(new caffe::Net(model_file, phase , NULL));